# Sorting a 2D array on 1 dimension

Tags: sorting, vba, excel

Inspired by a previous question, I was looking into converting a table to a sorted list (ascending) -

[image]

Resulting in this -

[image]

I used a very simple bubble-sort, but I don't know how efficient that would be with larger data sets, either in records or if I wanted to sort on more than one condition. Basically, this was an exercise in using arrays when built-in excel tools would be better.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetBids()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim customer As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim size As Long
    Dim sortedBids As Variant
    counter = 1

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    size = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)))

    Dim arrayOfBids As Variant
    ReDim arrayOfBids(1 To size, 1 To 2)
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        customer = Cells(i, 1)
        For j = 2 To lastColumn
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then
            arrayOfBids(counter, 1) = Cells(i, j)
            arrayOfBids(counter, 2) = customer
            counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    sortedBids = BubbleSort(arrayOfBids)
    Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(size, 7)) = sortedBids

End Sub

Private Function BubbleSort(ByVal arrayOfBids As Variant) As Variant
    Dim temporaryArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim exchangeMade As Boolean
    ReDim temporaryArray(1 To 1, 1 To 2)

    Do
        exchangeMade = True
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrayOfBids) - 1
            If arrayOfBids(i, 1) > arrayOfBids(i + 1, 1) Then
                exchangeMade = False
                temporaryArray(1, 1) = arrayOfBids(i, 1)
                temporaryArray(1, 2) = arrayOfBids(i, 2)
                arrayOfBids(i, 1) = arrayOfBids(i + 1, 1)
                arrayOfBids(i, 2) = arrayOfBids(i + 1, 2)
                arrayOfBids(i + 1, 1) = temporaryArray(1, 1)
                arrayOfBids(i + 1, 2) = temporaryArray(1, 2)
            End If
        Next i
    Loop While Not (exchangeMade)

    BubbleSort = arrayOfBids
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overall, pretty good code.  There are a couple things I would personally change though.

**1** - I'd start by qualifying the references to `Cells` and `Range` even if it's assumed that everything is done with the same sheet - I'd grab a reference to `ActiveSheet` right at the start and use that throughout. Using a `Worksheet` reference inside a `With` block is much faster than using the global objects. Outside of the performance, it's generally a good habit to get into as it avoids using an implicit reference.

**2** - The call to calculate the size of the array is a bit of overkill - there really isn't a need for a function call with:

```
size = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)))
```

You already have all the information you need to calculate it with a simple multiplication:

```
size = (lastRow - 1) * (lastColumn - 1)
```

Excel is almost certainly doing more work to count it, because a `Range` object doesn't have to be rectangular.

**3** - You *write* your array by setting the `.Value` of the target `Range` to the array, but your *reads* are still done inside of a loop.  Not only that, but you read the same value (`Cells(i, j)`) from the worksheet twice here:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then
arrayOfBids(counter, 1) = Cells(i, j)
```

Remember, `Cells(r, c)` is a *function call* (2 actually - see #1) so you should be caching the result if the return value isn't going to change between the calls. I'd read the source `Range` into an array also and then iterate over that.

**4** - While I'm on that section of code, the block enclosed by...

```
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then
'...
End If
```

...should be indented another level.

**5** - `IsEmpty` probably isn't the best choice (see [this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139668/36565)) - you really just need to test that the cell isn't equal to `vbNullString`. Or if a zero bid is invalid, test that the cell isn't equal to 0.

**6** - `temporaryArray` is basically being used as a tuple to store the swap values in your `BubbleSort` implementation.  However, when you store them in an array you carry a bunch of SafeArray overhead along with it, especially since it's curiously a two dimensional array with the first dimension fixed at 1 element. A one dimensional array would be better (the runtime performs a multiply internally every time you address a cell in a 2D array). Even better would be to create a simple type to store them in:

```
Private Type Tuple
    ItemOne As Variant
    ItemTwo As Variant
End Type
```

**7** - One small advantage that a bubble sort has is that it sorts the array in place.  But..., your implementation takes the array `ByVal` and then just returns a copy of the sorted array when it's done. This is a *huge* performance hit that negates the advantage of an in-place sort. Think of it in terms of memory copies.  The call `sortedBids = BubbleSort(arrayOfBids)` creates a copy of `sortedBids` in memory and then passes it to `BubbleSort`. The `BubbleSort` function then sorts the *copy* in place. But the copy is just a locally scoped variable, so finally you call `BubbleSort = arrayOfBids` which copies it *again* and puts it on the stack as the return value.  Take advantage of possible the sole benefit of your algorithm and convert `BubbleSort` to a `Sub` that takes the array `ByRef`.

**8** - Your counter `i` should be declared as a `Long` in `BubbleSort`.  I'd actually consider this a bug, because the variables you use to size the array you pass it are `Long`. Speaking of which, you also need overflow protection in `GetBids()`. `WorksheetFunction.Count` returns a `Double` which it has to because the total number of possible cells in a `Range` is 17,179,869,184 (the maximum possible return value in your code is 17,178,804,225). This will easily overflow a `Long`.  Granted, you won't be able to write the results if it overflows (and I shudder to think of the execution time for a bubble sort with 1,048,575 elements), but a graceful exit would be nicer than an unhandled exception.

**9** - The return value of `UBound(arrayOfBids)` will never change inside your `Do` loop in `BubbleSort`. This value should also be cached outside of the loop - there isn't a need for repeated function calls to determine what is essentially a static value.

**10** - You should swap the order of your data collection loops. Based on the sample data, the values on each row should always be increasing from left to right. This indicates that the final placement of an element in the sorted output is more strongly correlated by which *column* it's in instead of which *row* it's in. But when you're building the `arrayOfBids` that is eventually going to be sorted, you're building it in row order *then* column order.  While this doesn't make as much of a difference with a bubble sort as it would with other sort algorithms, you are basically ensuring that your input to the sort will be closer to the worst case than it will to the best case.  If you switch the loop order to this...

```
For j = 2 To lastColumn
    For i = 2 To lastRow
    Next
Next
```

...you are using this characteristic of your typical data set to make sure your sort input is closer to best case.

Comment: *Or if a zero bid is invalid, test that the cell isn't equal to 0.* - that, and I think I'd go as far as taking a negative, or any bid that isn't a positive integer as an illegal value. Then you need some custom error-raising mechanism, and a nice way for your client code to handle these errors, e.g. use the exact original (string) value but write it in bold red with a flashy yellow background on the worksheet, or not - but then you have grounds for wrapping it all up in a class module and play with an *object*, or give it a dflt.instance and let the client code use it as a global-scope tool.

Comment: I always mess up point 1. Thanks. As for the count, I'm accounting for any cells that don't have a bid rather than just making it the size of the possible bids, because I couldn't resize it afterwards. 7 - OH NO I SHOULD KNOW BETTER!

Comment: @Raystafarian - Re: the count (to borrow your phrase) "OH NO I SHOULD KNOW BETTER".  You're right that I completely missed the purpose there - and empty elements at the end would *all* be turtles in an ascending bubble sort.